# Acer Aspire V3-571G Fan Settings

Tags: bios, fan

My laptop is very hot I just bought it like 2 days ago. It most of the times up to 60 c and the only thing I have open is Google Chrome or just only Skype, I think it's way too hot for just one program.

I want to change the fan speed I tried from the Bios settings and couldn't find it but then I saw there was a new update, I updated it and I still can't seem to change the fan speed.

I tried FanSpeed, NVIDA Inspector and things like that, I can't change it there either.
Even tho NVIDIA Inspector allows me to overclock but I'm afraid that will damage things, also since the laptop is new.

So.. How do I change the fan speed?

Comment: What's the temperature like in your environment? Regardless, fans are automatically controlled to allow the system to operate in relatively safe temperatures. Also, placing your laptop in a completely flat surface helps it to better "breathe".

Comment: The laptop is on a cooler, its not really flat tho, a litle bit higher on the back, but here where I live its 30 c if that's what you meant lol.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find a few other solutions via this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/295513/how-can-i-set-the-fan-speed-to-100-on-a-laptop).

In any case, you might want to try closing unnecessary background processes that might be causing your processor to use up more power than what's actually needed. Running [PC Decrapifier](http://pcdecrapifier.com/) may also help. It might also be a case of malware - in which case, use anti-malware software such as [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your hardware specs...

Changing the fan speed is not the solution I'd be looking for. 60 C doesn't sound ridiculously high depending on the CPU load. On my core i7-680UM the temp idles at around 50C-55C and up to 75 C under load with turbo boost kicking in. You can check the maximum operating temperature of your CPU at the manufacturer's site. Have you searched to see what other temps folk are getting with the same setup and CPU? Fan speed is normally controlled by the BIOS and depending on your hardware, software control is not always possible/very difficult.

I'd recommend you do the following:

- Check in to see what processes are running in task manager or your OS equivalent. If it's a new laptop (or old!) there might be a load of 'bloatware' running causing high CPU usage. Remove these using the add/remove programs in the control panel. Or, alternatively, use another piece of software to do this as recommended in the other answer. I can't advise one over another though I'd be careful as some of these can be 'malware'.
- Consider a laptop cooling matt/stand. I use one for my Acer 1830T and it does an excellent job. There is a fan built into the stand that is powered via a USB port on the laptop.

Edit: Apologies, I've just seen your model in the title. The CPU is an  i5-3230M, the Intel data sheet is [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/72164/)

I wouldn't lose any sleep over it. Follow the previous advice about removing software not required that might be using system resources and consider a stand/matt.